# composer package - CiviCRM + WordPress Blueprint

Tags: composer

I am experimenting with roots/bedrock, roots/soil, roots/sage "platform" as the "sage" theme sounds compelling and the dependency management inhernet in composer is also compelling.

To that end, I used composer to install the package "civicrm + wordpress blueprint".  It appears the install "script" requires a .env root level file to be populated post install with db name, db user, localhost, domain, and also the # Generate your keys here (wrap them in quotes): https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/...

I then modified/populated the .env file from command line.  But, I am uncertain what to do next... anyone have any experience here?

Steps taken so far are;
composer create-project jbradach/wordpress-civicrm
created db & db user, secret keys, etc
updated .env file with key details from previous step

I just don't know what the command or step is to finalize the "set-up" and I can find no docs.  Help appreciated.

++++++++++++

As an aside, the purpose of this exercise is to "test" the /roots/bedrock/soil/sage/ building blocks.  I am most interested in the "themeing" front end functionalities and apparent compatibilities with wp/civi.  thoughts?

Comment: Did you try steps 5 and 6 at https://github.com/jbradach/civicrm-wordpress?

Comment: If it's a cpanel setup then I wouldn't update cpanel's files manually. Just in cpanel via browser where you set up the domain you set the domain's root to be the `"web"` subfolder under whatever folder you installed the package via composer. So if you ran `composer create-project` under /home/user/public_html/wordpress-civicrm, then you set the root for the domain in cpanel to /home/user/public_html/wordpress-civicrm/web. Step 3 at https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/78Docs/Domains.

Comment: cpanel support advised this process...
#5 set document root to /path/to/site/web folder... 
ssh'd into whm/cpanel server account
#/var/cpanel/userdata/yourusername
*update "documentroot" field in each file yourdomain.com and yourdomain.com_SSL
documentroot: /home/yourusername/public_html/wordpress-civicrm/web/
#/scripts/updateuserdatacache
#/scripts/buildhttpdconf
#/scripts/restartsrv_httpd
6 Access WP admin at http://example.com/wp/wp-admin
attempted http://example.com/wp/wp-admin/install.php or index.php, both 500 error.

Comment: composer.json file path is /home/username/public_html/wordpress-civicrm/composer.json